# Should MSI files from different versions for one product named identically

Tags: installation, windows-installer

I have 2 msi files. First for version 1.0.0.120 and second for version 1.2.0.321

should I named them as 
product.1.0.0.120.msi
product.1.2.0.321.msi

so when user/admin download the product they exactly know about the version and choose the correct project or I should keep the name <> to make easy the upgrade for MSI engine?

Comment: At minimum, it's general convention to prefix with 'Setup'.

Comment: When you change the name of the .msi file, you prevent use of minor upgrades between these versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't really matter. But some unwritten conventions are:

- like  Mr. Disappointment mentioned, the word "setup" should be in the name, for example "Product Name Setup"
- for often releases (at least once a month) your setup name shouldn't contain the product version
- for rare release (once every 6 months) your setup name should contain the product version

In the end it's up to you. For your users it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Note: if you didn't change the product code in Wix project and then update your product using REINSTALL=ALL RESINSTALMODE=vamus then you need to keep MSI file name (got this from outside of StOw)